# Need a way to backport serialize() to xquery1.0

Tags: xquery, wso2-micro-integrator

I'd like to put an xml node as CDATA in the output document and I have to use xquery1.0

How can I backport `serialize()`?

I have `Saxon-HE-9.5.1-8.jar` as XQuery processor provided by wso2-mi

Comment: Which XQuery processor is that?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Added to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know details about Saxon 9.5 but it is not an old, pure XQuery 1.0 processor but somewhere between the two versions; so perhaps trying

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:cdata-section-elements 'foo';
```

works.